# need idea for project : how to invite people to group chat? (Spring_EJB_JMS_Glassfish)

Tags: java, spring, glassfish, ejb, jms

I am doing an server-client group chat application in java using these technology: JMS, EJB(Remote stateless, message driven bean), Spring(dependency inject), Hibernate(database stuff). I have an user(username,password) table in mysql database. The problem is it requires: after login user can invite other users to chat with him and I have no idea how to do that? So if I invite someone I have to create a new topic in glassfish or are there anyway to use 1 topic? How do I create topic in glassfish at runtime? Someone suggest me to use selector to filter the message so that i don't have to create multiple topic, can it be done like that? And how can I communicate with other user in my application to send invitation to them? So anyone can suggest me any idea, code, example... on how to do that would be appreciated. For so far. I have managed to make users chat to each other in the topic that I predefined in glassfish web console. Here are a part of my client code.

```
Context ctx;
            try {
                Properties props = new Properties();

                ctx = new InitialContext(props);
                tcf = (TopicConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("p2scon");
                tpConnection = tcf.createTopicConnection(); // anomyous access
                tpConnection.setClientID(tfName.getText());

                // false means the TopicSession will not be transacted
                // acknowledgment mode used by the JMS client.
                // An acknowledgment is a notification to the message server that the client has received the messag
                // AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE means the message is automatically acknowledged after it is received by the client
                tpSession = tpConnection.createTopicSession(false, TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                // look up JMS topic
                topic = (Topic) ctx.lookup("p2sdes");
                tpPublisher = tpSession.createPublisher(topic);

               /* Nondurable subscribers are temporary subscriptions that receive messages only when
                they are actively listening on the topic. Durable subscribers, on the other hand, will
                receive a copy of every message published, even if they are “offline” when the message
                is published.*/
                tpSubscribe = tpSession.createDurableSubscriber(topic, tfName.getText());
                tpSubscribe.setMessageListener(MainFrame1.this);
                tpConnection.start();
                /*t = new Thread(MainFrame1.this);
                t.start();*/
                btnConnect.setVisible(false);
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't connect");
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't connect");
            }
```

Comment: You do know that even though JMS stands for `Java Messaging Service`, it's not really something you'd use for a chat application?

Comment: yes! I know! but still. this is a project that my mentor ask me to do so there's  nothing I can do. just have to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to communicate between processes and machines, you'll need a messaging service, such as [Apache's ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/).
To invite users to join a topic, you'll need another communication method.  Two patterns spring to ming:

- Each user logs in to the application.  Once a user is logged in, another user can invite them to a chat by sending a P2P message, which (if accepted) causes them to subscribe to a topic.  In this case, users would need to log in before invites can be sent, but users can have a status, like XMPP's "presence".
- A user can invite anyone to a topic, which sends an offline communication (probably an email) requesting they log in and join.  As well as inviting users who aren't currently logged in, this would allow users to invite friends who haven't previously used the service.  But then subscribing to the topic would be a manual process once they've logged in.

In general, if you want ideas of patterns for chat services, it's a good idea to check out [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/).